# Show that continuous extension implies holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> We consider $f:\hat{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ which is
>   holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and has a continuous extension to
>   $\infty$. Then it follows that $f$ is holomorphic on
>   $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.

Does the following argument work as a proof? What are the details needed for a complete proof?

We consider the following cases:

1. If $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{C}$ then $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} f(z)=constant$ i.e. $f$ is constant on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.
2. If $f$ is non-constant on $\mathbb{C}$ then it is unbounded by Liouville. So $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} f(z)=\infty$ (since $f$ has a continuous extension to $\infty$). The set of zeros of $f$ is a discrete subset of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ hence a finite set. Let $g$ a polynomial with the same zeros and multiplicities as $f$ and consider $h=\frac{f}{g}$. The conclusion shouldn't be that $h$ is constant and $f$ is a polynomial? For this, the argument is that $h$ is an entire bounded function?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In this case $f$ has a continuous extension to $\infty$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg $g$ is defined as the polynomial with the same zeros and multiplicities as $f$ so for your example of $f$, $g(z)=z^3$ though.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg That is my question actually. I am asking whether that holds and in that way the argument works towards a proof of the initial statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\hat f:\hat {\mathbb C}\to \hat{\mathbb C}$ obtained by defining $\hat f(\infty)=\infty$ is continuous.
To prove that $\hat f$  is holomorphic at $\infty$ means that the continuous function $g$ defined near $0$ by $g(w) =\frac {1}{f(\frac  1w)}$ for $w\neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$ is holomorphic.
But this follows from [Riemann's removable singularities theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) acording to which a continuous function  on a domain that is  holomorphic outside  a point of that domain is actually holomorphic on the whole domain.